# Simple .NET Core console and class library projects cannot build - missing System namespace

Tags: c#, .net-core

I downloaded the .NET Core SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows and created a simple console application using `dotnet new console` for Core version 2, but when I build it with `dotnet build` I get 26 build errors between "The type or namespace 'System' could not be found" and "Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined" (the latter has some variation but they all originate from the system namespace). I checked the csproj-file but could not find anything out of the ordinay (I would not expect otherwise since all files are generated by dotnet):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I also tried calling `dotnet restore` but that returned the message `Restore completed in 34.26 ms for c:\Development\foo\foo.csproj.` so apparently nothing was wrong here. If I run `dotnet --info` in the project directory I get this information:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.200)

Product Information:
Version:            2.1.200
Commit SHA-1 hash:  2edba8d7f1

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.17134
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.7
Build    : 2d61d0b043915bc948ebf98836fefe9ba942be11
```

I successfully recreated the issue using a class library with `dotnet new classlib`. I also had a second laptop with dotnet installed on it and fortunately I was able to generate a class library on that laptop without any compile errors. I then compared the two projects using WinMerge and this is what I found - I will reference the working project with (a) and the faulty one with (b):

- NuGetToolVersion section in obj\[projectname].csproj.nuget.g.props is 4.4.0 in (a) and 4.7.0 in (b)
- NETStandard.Library is 2.0.0 in (a) and 2.0.1 in (b)
- ImportGroup section in obj\[projectname].csproj.nuget.g.targets is missing from (b)
- "build" key under "NETStandard.Library/2.0.*" in obj\project.assets.json is missing from (b)
- "files" key under "NETStandard.Library/2.0.*" in obj\project.assets.json is missing all .dll references in (b)
- "version" key under "frameworks" in obj\project.assets.json is set to "2.0.0" in (a) and "[2.0.1, )" in (b). The value in (b) is not a typo - this is obviously invalid syntax.

My guess is that the last 4 differences are the culprints but I don't know how to fix it or why this happens. It could be an error in the class library project template for dotnet but I still have doubts about that.

I should say that I installed the .NET Core SDK on a newly restored laptop so I suspect the issue is quite simple but I haven't found it yet. Does anyone have any idea why this happens or what I should check for?

Comment: I had the same issue, after changing .NET Core version from 1 to 2, it was built! Check your .NET Core version from project's properties.

Comment: Please could you show us the project file and the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: (And make sure you run `dotnet --info` in the same directory you're running `dotnet build`, as a `global.json` file can affect things!)

Comment: Run `dotnet restore` explicitly to see what it reports back.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all your suggestions - I have added them to my original question but unfortunately no change.

Comment: Hmm. That does all look okay. It's particularly odd given that this is a new environment, so no old versions lurking to cause issues. It may be worth uninstalling the SDK and reinstalling it?

Comment: Perhaps some hint could be found in more verbose output of the build? dotnet build /verbosity:d  (or /verbosity:diag for coffee break)

Comment: Sorry I tried to re-install the .NET Core library and pass in /verbosity:d when compiling but nothing helped. The verbose argument gave a lot of extra information but still the same compile errors. I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for in the verbose output?

Comment: I did some additional investigations comparing a healthy project with this one - my findings have been added to the description

Comment: I also created a post at https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9353 and I will update this thread in case someone posts a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was only able to solve the problem with a complete OS-restore (which was scheduled anyway). As I write this I'm running dotnet version 2.1.401 and have not encountered the issue since so I'm releasing this reply to the community wiki.

Details on the GitHub issue is at https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9353